# Am I allowed to promote a Discord server?

Tags: support

Am I allowed to promote a Discord server for a writing project that I want to include the community in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it depends on how you intend to go about doing it.

- Promoting the server in your profile - either in the dedicated "website" field or in your "About me" section - is perfectly fine.
- Promoting the server in [the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) would *probably* be fine, as long as you're not doing it too often. Spamming the link constantly will annoy people and could potentially get you suspended from chat.
- Promoting the server in your questions/answers/comments would almost certainly *not* be allowed. At best, it would be considered noise, and edited out. At worst, it would be flagged as spam. I can't think of a scenario in which a Discord invite link would be relevant to a question or answer.

You may also want to check out the help article on [how to not be a spammer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).